# Elegant solution to this digit puzzle

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

## Puzzle

The letters $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$ represent single digits and each letter represents a different digit. They satisfy the following equations:
$$
a+b=d, \quad b+c=e \quad \text { and } \quad d+e=f \text {. }
$$
Find all possible solutions for the values of $a, b, c, d, e$ and $f$.

This is clearly easily solved by computer, but what is an elegant and hopefully quick way of doing it by hand?

Answer (score 10):

Solutions:

> Eight possible permutations

Explanation:

> By manupulating the equations, we get a+2b+c=f=d+e. This means that the least possible value of f must be 7, since none of the numbers can be zero; however, this means (a,c) belongs to {2,3} and b=1, but it doesn't satisfy e and f. So the only two possibilities for f are 8 and 9.

> For f=8, b must be less than 3. For a,c = {1,3}, b=2, we don't have a solution so it is discarded. On to the next solution b=1, a,c={2,4}, we get d,e={3,5} so two solutions from f=8.

> For f=9, b must be lesser than 4. For b=3, a,c={1,2} is the only possibility and d,e={4,5} hence it satisfies all equations. For b=2, a,c = {1,4} is the only possibility once again and d,e = {6,3}. This also satisfies all equations. For b=1, we have a,c = {2,5} or {3,4}. But a,c = {3,4} does not satisfy as d,e = {4,5} which has 4 as a common digit. For a,c = {2,5}, we have d,e = {3,6} and it satisfies all the equations.

> Hence there are 6 solutions for f=9 and 2 solutions for f=8. Therefore the total number of solutions is 8.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your notation but how do you get 2 solutions in the second spoiler box? Either a,c={2,4} means a=2 and c=4 and similarly for d,e={3,5} so only one solution or it means {a,c}={2,4} with the two solutions a=2,c=4 and a=4, c=2 and similarly for d and e which gives 4 solutions in total.

Comment: @quarague Its only exactly two solutions for the second spoiler box. Look at the original equations to see the direct correspondence between a and d.

Comment: So you do mean {a,c}={2,4} and {d,e}={3,5} which on its own would give 4 solutions but the original equations give an additional condition so you only have 2 solutions. Maybe extend your explanation a little bit to include that.

Comment: d,e are governed by a,b and c so for different value of a,b,c there will only one possibility of d and e. I should have elaborated but I tried to keep it concise.

Answer (score 8):

Overall, I've counted

> Eight solutions

so there will inevitably be some degree of case bashing.
This is how I would proceed.

Notice firstly that

> None of the digits is zero since that would make some of the others equal or negative.

Suppose $f < 9$

> Then either $d$ or $e$ is less than $4$ (since they are distinct). Since both are the sum of distinct digits, it must be that the smaller of the two is $3$ and the other is $4$ or $5$.
>  Firstly, suppose that this $d=3$. Then $a$ and $b$ must be $1$ and $2$ in some order. Since $e$ must be $4$ or $5$ its clear that $b$ cannot be $2$ (since $c$ would have to be $2$ or $3$) and if $b=1$ then $c=4$ and $e=5$ is the only possible solution. This gives us the first solution $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (2,1,4,3,5,8)$$
>  Since the equations remain the same if we swap $d$ with $e$ and $a$ with $c$, we quickly obtain a second solution which comes from assuming $e=3$ instead $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (4,1,2,5,3,8)$$ and these are all the solutions in this branch

Now suppose $f=9$

> Then $d$ and $e$ are either $3$ and $6$ or $4$ and $5$, in some order (since we've established that both $d$ and $e$ must be at least $3$).
>  $d=3$ gives us that $a$ and $b$ are $1$ and $2$ in some order.
>  With $b=2$ we must have $c=4$ and this gives another solution $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (1,2,4,3,6,9)$$
>  With $b=1$ we must have $c=5$ and we have yet another solution $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (2,1,5,3,6,9)$$
>  Again, we can reverse the role of $(d,e)$ and $(a,c)$ to retrieve the solutions in the $e=3$ branch $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (4,2,1,6,3,9)$$ $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (5,1,2,6,3,9)$$
>  Finally, $d=4$ gives us $a$ and $b$ being $1$ and $3$ in some order.
>  $b=1$ doesn't work because it would mean $c=4=d$.
>  $b=3$ gives us another solution $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (1,3,2,4,5,9)$$ and swapping $(d,e)$ and $(a,c)$ gives us the last solution which comes from the $e=4$ branch $$(a,b,c,d,e,f) = (2,3,1,5,4,9)$$

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to 'see' what the solutions looked like, but I disqualified myself by using a computer to get the solutions. Anyway, here is a visualization for your amusement.

## Visualization

> The nodes of this hypergraph are the possible digit values that occurred in at least one solution. The coloured set covers are the hyperedges. The hyperedges are labelled 0-to-7 for the eight solutions.
>  [image: ![enter image description here]

## Observation

> It looks like all solutions cover the set $\{1,2,3\}$. Maybe a simple rule based on these three special choices can be constructed to get what the remaining digits of the solution have to be (i.e. how to pick the remaining $\{4,5,6,8\}$). The number 7 doesn't get to join the party.

---

## Code for Visualization

```
import hypernetx as hnx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import permutations

values = set(range(10))


solutions = {}
sol_count = 0
for perm in permutations(values, r=6):
    a,b,c,d,e,f = perm
    if a + b == d:
        if b + c == e:
            if d + e == f:
                print(a,b,c,d,e,f)
                solutions[str(sol_count)] = perm
                sol_count += 1
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
    
H = hnx.Hypergraph(solutions)

hnx.drawing.draw(H)
plt.show()
```

Comment: rot13: Zl pbqr vf cerggl anvir. Bar guvat lbh pbhyq punatr vs lbh jnagrq vg eha zber rssvpvragyl vf gb ercynpr `inyhrf = frg(enatr(10))` jvgu `inyhrf = frg(enatr(1,10)) - {7}` fvapr mreb naq frira ner arire va gur fbyhgvbaf sbe guvf ceboyrz.